# Adding two separate ajax Post rquest results together

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two separate Ajax Post requests that i need to add together, they are both linking to a currency exchange feed, its basically two values that get converted from different currencies and then need to be added together after both being converted to one currency, ive gotten them both on the same currency no i just need to add the two results together to get a final total.

Here are the two requests

```
    var dataString = "amount=" + entireTotal + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;
        //Lets Get the exchange rates from our total
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://fileserver/website/modules/mod_calculation/js/currency.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function(data){
        $('#inputresult').show();
        //Put received response into result div
         $('#inputresult').html(data);
       }
     });

var dataString = "amount=" + amountGel + "&from=" + fromGel + "&to=" + toGel;
            $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://fileserver/website/modules/mod_calculation/js/currencygel.php",
       data:  dataString,
       success: function(data){
           $('#resultsgel').html(data);
         //Show results div
         $('#resultsgel').show();
        //Put received response into result div
       }
     });
```

any help at all will be much apreciated.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var request1 = $.ajax({ ... }),
    request2 = $.ajax({ ... });

$.when(request1, request2).then(function(response1, response2) { ... })
```

Further reading:

- A good article about how to use promises in jQuery: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/
- And the [official documentation pages](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Small abstract example similar to what you need (sorry, don't have enough time to create ajax requests there, but they behave exactly the same): http://jsfiddle.net/Y26zd/

Comment: interesting approach, repped +1

Comment: Hey Thanks, 90% of the way there, It works, i Just need to now add the two Response values together? any idea... "601,150.9,success,[object Object]" that what im currently getting. I just need the numbers, that the value

Comment: @Dawid van der Hoven: we don't know what you return and what your current code is (that returns what you've shown)

Comment: well its giving me a success,[object Object], When all i need is the responseText?, Im sorry im new to AJAX. Thanks any way, ill Try and see if i can find the solution, and thanks @zerkims Your Awesome. Helped me alot thanks :)

Comment: @Dawid van der Hoven: what "it"? Show some code that does that. Open chrome developer tools or firebug and look what the server returns back to you

Comment: Well, im inserting the result this way $('#finaltotal').fadeIn("slow").html(response1 + response2); and then im also doing this console.log(response1, response2);... and it gives me this on the html (601,173.2,success,[object Object]R273,405.00,success,[object Object]) and on the console its giving me " ["601,173.2", "success", Object { readyState=4,  responseText="601,173.2",  status=200,  more...}]["R273,405.00", "success", Object { readyState=4,  responseText="R273,405.00",  status=200,  more...}] "

Comment: @Dawid van der Hoven: well, now you see the structure of the retrieved data. It's javascript the very basics :-)