# Post 2 data using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem and I really need help. Im trying to post from the jsp to the controller 2 data in just 1 ajax post.

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: contextPath + "/generalLedger/journalEntries/form",
        data : {"json" : glEntries, "searchParam" : searchData},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success!!!");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
});
```

In my controller:

```
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST,  value = "/form")
public String postJournalEntry (@RequestBody String json, @RequestBody String searchParam, Model model) {
    // Some codes here
}
```

My problem is that Im having :

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:188)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToString(FileCopyUtils.java:240)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:62)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestBody(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:552)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at bp.servlet.CBSDispatcherServlet.doService(CBSDispatcherServlet.java:37)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Im still new to this. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to get the values of the parameters at the controller which you are sending through AJAX.

Comment: No. When I try to click the button that triggers post I get the error.

Comment: well you should debug your code at backend. and you can also do one thing if you are sending the values from a particular HTML form, then you can use **var data = $("#form-id").serialize();** This method will send all the parameter of your form at controller and you can even get those parameters as **String param1 = req.getParameter("param1");**

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671348/adding-two-separate-ajax-post-rquest-results-together

Answer (score 0):

In jquery code line,

```
data : {"json" : glEntries, "searchParam" : searchData},
```

Should be,

```
data : {json : glEntries, searchParam : searchData},
```

Comment: @NinjaBoy, make one test file contain just "test ok", and then use test file as url in ajax request. Check out, you got success alert or not.